# User-defined Output Stream Manipulators in C

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, and in the part of user-defined output stream manipulatior, I am stuck.
This is the example code:

```
    #include <iostream>
     using std::cout;
     using std::flush;
     using std::ostream;

    ostream& endLine( ostream& output )
    {
      return output << '\n' << flush;
    }

    int main()
    {
       cout << "Testing:" << endLine;
       return 0;
    }
```

My question is, in the definition of endLine, there is an argument. But in the main function, why it is endLine only without brackets and according arguments.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. If you don't explicitly ask a question, we have to guess what you want explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::basic_ostream` has several overloads of `operator<<`, one of which has the following signature:

> ```
> basic_ostream& operator<<( basic_ostream& st, 
>                        std::basic_ostream& (*func)(std::basic_ostream&) );
> ```

That is, this function takes a pointer to a function that both takes and returns `std::ios_base`. The method is called by this function and is incorporated into the input/output operation. Thereby making this possible:

```
std::cout << endLine;
```

So what will happen is that `endLine` is converted into a function pointer and a new line character will be written to the stream and afterwards a flush operation.

Answer (score 2):

std::ostream has an overload of `operator<<` that takes a pointer to a function (or something similar that can be invoked, anyway) that accepts the pointer, and invokes the function, passing itself as a parameter to the function:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, ostream &(*f)(ostream &os)) { 
    return f(*this);
}
```

The version that's built in to `ostream` comes from `std::ios_base` (and that's the type it uses for the parameter and return), but if you're trying to write your own, you typically want to use `std::ostream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`cout`'s left shift operator calls `endLine` with `cout` as an argument. Functions (technically function pointers) don't need to be called when you write their names; you can pass them around as values and have some other code call them later.