# Trivial clarification regarding skipws declaration

Tags: c++, io

In `skipws`'s header, prototype: `std::ios_base& skipws( **std::ios_base& str** );` (from [Skipws/Noskipws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)) what is the part which I've put between ***asterisk*** sign, sure that the format flag **skipws** can't be used as a function. So what is it?

[image]

Comment: um, `skipws` is a function.  The stuff between the `()` of a function is called the function's paramter(s).  Not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: @NathanOliver But the compiler is saying that it can't be used as a function.

Comment: What is the code you are using that generates that error? [Works just fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f1ddd2846a57641)

Comment: @NathanOliver the erroneous part of my code was using: std::ios_base::skipws rather than std::skipws, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skipws` is a function, but you don't normally invoke it directly. Rather, you pass it to the stream:

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws >> foo;
std::cin >> std::skipws >> bar;
```

The stream has a special overload of `operator>>` that takes the right type (pointer to function ...) and invokes it on the stream on your behalf.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain this part: "that takes the right type (pointer to function ...) and invokes it on the stream on your behalf."

Comment: @Gaurav: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17479947/179910 shows what I'm talking about.